# How to solve null pointer exception at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.RPCInInterceptor.handleMessage()

Tags: java, web-services, apache, soap

How to solve the below exception....
Am using org.apache.cxf V2.3.0

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:146)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at $Proxy44.retrieveCPEOrders(Unknown Source)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.praveen.src.bookService.wsClient.ServiceClient.getDetails(ServiceClient.java:61)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
.
.
.
.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.RPCInInterceptor.handleMessage(RPCInInterceptor.java:166)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:247)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:733)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2201)
.
.
.
```

In logs I can see the response.. but after retrieving the response its throwing the error...

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I created the java codes from the WSDL using Apache-cfx 2.3.0